# using result of SELECT in another SELECT

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do question 9 here:
https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

I currently have the code:

```
  SELECT continent, SUM(y.population) as Population
    FROM world AS y
    GROUP BY(y.continent)
    HAVING SUM(y.population) < 250000000;
```

This returns the continents with a sum of their respective populations less than 250000000. I know I need to encase this in another select to make use of the continent returned, but don't know how to do this?
I tried something like this:

```
SELECT A.continent from world A
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT B.continent, SUM(B.population) as Population
  FROM world B
GROUP BY(B.continent)
HAVING SUM(B.population) < 250000000
) ON A.continent = B.continent;
```

^This was to try and get a single list of the continents which i could then encase in another select to iterate through and print the country names, although I feel there must be a way to directly iterate through the continent column from the first example?

This is likely something pretty trivial, but regardless any help would be great

Comment: which database are you using

Comment: A (last) comment re the post you just deleted: I have tried to help you & I told you what to do & specifically my last comment gave my best guess at what your slides might mean by "multi-valued" and that you need to find out exactly what it means, which is not what you think it means given what your post says. As far as I can tell your link is not even calling SalesPerson# "multi-valued", in any of the ways the word is used. But "multi-valued" & "1NF" *do not have fixed meanings* so if you don't reference or quote your slides or textbook we can't help you.

Comment: @philipxy I told you exactly what it means. I know exactly what it means. The textbook I linked uses the exact same terminology of "multivalued". The lecturer has taught me that salesPerson would be a multivalued attribute. An attribute that holds multiple values. Hence multivalued attribute. I genuinely don't know how much clearer that can be. Instead of replying to a question you nitpicked terminology and were condescending in your response. "figure out what you're trying to say" isn't a resemblance of any kind of help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to solve this - i used a count of all countries on the continent = count of countries with population<25000000
your main mistake is in logic - SUM - it should be EACH country, not the summary

```
select name,w1.continent,population
from world w1
join 
(
SELECT distinct continent, count(name) cnt
FROM world x
WHERE population<=25000000
group by continent
)w2
on w1.continent=w2.continent
where cnt=(select count(name) from world where w1.continent=continent)
```